What happened in May 10/2022 for the drop of new visits?
According to our stats page there is a drop of around May 10/2022 from 2000 to 300 of the new visits. We may argue that it was ChatGPT, however, is not possible since it was released on November 30, 2022.
Is there a known reason for this drop?


ChatGPT became more widely available on May the 25th (Germany, France) and you could subscribe to ChatGPT plus since February. It might also have to do something with the way Google ranks pages; I see more links to sites that collect bad answers / examples and have horrid cookie policies lately.

Here's some meta Q/A for this. The drop was the main reason for SE to take action on mods removing ChatGPT answers. Fortunately that's in the past now and those kind of answers are not showing up anymore anyway (which of course shows that this wasn't really the problem in the first place, and it could not explain the drop in visits & views anyway).

I see. I still prefer the the AI must provide the links to their answer so all can give credit to it. In one of my projects I hardly find a solution ( thanks to almost zero documentation of Apple and their lack of ). I needed to combine the solutions of Bard and ChatGPT. I wonder where they took it. Thanks for the comments.

The Bing Chat does give references. It's not a very strong bot (the data set is way smaller), but it is up to date at least.
